# How to change object property returned by a function to make the function reusable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to edit the following function to make it usable throughout my application:

```
function data(){
  let nested = nest().key(function(d) { return d.location_name })
      .key(function(d) { return d.customer_id})
}
```

In order to make this reusable, the return of the first .key function needs to mutable. For example I might want the function to be something like:

```
function data(){    
let nested = nest().key(function(d) { return d.consultant_name})
              .key(function(d) { return d.customer_id})
};
```

I'm not sure how to do this because I am returning a property of 'd'.

I first tried to put it in a variable that passed in as an argument:

```
let example = d.location_name

function data(example){
  let nested = nest().key(function(d) { return example})
      .key(function(d) { return d.customer_id})
}

data(example)
```

But this gives me 'd is undefined' errors and I understand why. Is there a specific methodology to use for reusable functions with object properties?

Comment: please add `nest`. `var` as variable is not possible.

Comment: You can't use both `let` and `var` in same statement, change to e.g. `let loc_name = d.location_name`

Comment: apologies, simply bad placeholder management on my part

Comment: I am staring to find the difference between the first two code blocks. What am I missing? Secondly, what does `arr` refer to?

Comment: The copied blocks are part of a larger function which uses the `arr`. The difference between the first two blocks is the return property of the first key function. sdgluck has provided the answer I was looking for and I'll be more careful about my examples in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept the property name you want to access as an argument:

```
function data (key) {    
  let nested = nest().key(function(d) { return d[key]})
    .key(function(d) { return d.customer_id})
    .entries(arr)
};

// e.g.
// data('location_name')
// data('consultant_name')
```